# Setting Color With Array Data Format in Highcharts Funnel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have attached the funnel visualization code that I have so far.

```js
$(function() {
  var dataEx = [
      ['1 Visit', 352000],
      ['2 Visits', 88000],
      ['3+ Visits', 42000]
    ],
    len = dataEx.length,
    sum = 0,
    minHeight = 0.05,
    data = [];
    
   //specify your percent of prior visit value manually here:
   
   var perc = [100, 25, 48];

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += dataEx[i][1];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var t = dataEx[i],
      r = t[1] / sum;
    data[i] = {
      name: t[0],
      y: (r > minHeight ? t[1] : sum * minHeight),
      percent: perc[i],   // <----- this here is manual input
   //percent: Math.round(r * 100),    <--- this here is mathematical
      label: t[1]
    }
  }
  console.log(dataEx, data)
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'funnel',
      marginRight: 100,


      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
           var bBox = p.dataLabel.getBBox()
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle',
              y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
            })
          })
        },
        redraw: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle',
              y: p.labelPos.y - (bBox.height / 2)
            })
          })
        }
      },
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Guest Return Funnel',
      x: -50
    },
    tooltip: {
      //enabled: false
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.key +
          '</b><br/>Percent of Prior Visit: '+ this.point.percent + '%<br/>Guests: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.label, 0);
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {


        allowPointSelect: true,
        borderWidth: 12,

        animation: {
          duration: 400
        },


        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,

          connectorWidth: 0,
          distance: 0,

          formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point;
            console.log(point);
            return '<b>' + point.name + '</b> (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.label, 0) + ')<br/>' + point.percent + '%';
          },
          minSize: '10%',
          color: 'black',
          softConnector: true
        },

        neckWidth: '30%',
        neckHeight: '0%',
        width: '50%',
        height: '110%'


        //old options are as follows:

        //neckWidth: '50%',
        //neckHeight: '50%',
        //-- Other available options
        //height: '200'
        // width: pixels or percent
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Unique users',
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

What I want to do is manually change the color of each category (piece) of the funnel (for example, maybe first category red, second category orange, third category yellow). I know that there are some ways to enter in data into a series in Highcharts such as:

[['CATEOGRY', 'VALUE],...['CATEGORY','VALUE']]

or you can do an array with names value and specify something like

color: "#00FF00" inside of it.

So maybe I can use the second form of writing data into a series cause you can specify color.

However, how would I be able to specify color of the pieces WHILE ALSO ensuring that the data processing algorithm to scale when there are small values works and the rest of the code works?

Also, is there any way to specify color given the current array of data that I have in my code? Being dataEx = [['CATEOGRY', 'VALUE],...['CATEGORY','VALUE']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the color as the third element in dataEx array and then set it as a point color:

```
var dataEx = [
        ['1 Visit', 352000, 'red'],
        ['2 Visits', 88000, 'orange'],
        ['3+ Visits', 42000, 'yellow']
    ],
    len = dataEx.length,
    sum = 0,
    minHeight = 0.05,
    data = [];

//specify your percent of prior visit value manually here:

var perc = [100, 25, 48];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += dataEx[i][1];
}

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var t = dataEx[i],
        r = t[1] / sum;
    data[i] = {
        name: t[0],
        color: t[2],
        y: (r > minHeight ? t[1] : sum * minHeight),
        percent: perc[i], // <----- this here is manual input
        //percent: Math.round(r * 100),    <--- this here is mathematical
        label: t[1]
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8be3c1sm/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.funnel.data.color